# AngularJS - Video Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, video

I have a template whereby I load details into via a JSON file. The content that is loaded in accompanies a video embed. Everything from the JSON files are working great, but the same video appears on every item. Is there a way that I can load individual videos assigned to each JSON file?

Here is the template:

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="guide in guides">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <br/>
    <p><a ng-href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Back to Guide List</a></p>
    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span> Watch {{ guide.title }}</h1>

    <span>{{ guide.info }}</span><br/><br/>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12">    
    <video video="marvel">
    </video><!--This is the bit I'm having an issue with -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> Background to {{ guide.title }}</h3>
    <span>{{ guide.background }}</span><br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">

    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Downloads for {{ guide.title }}</h3><br/>

                <a ng-href="{{ guide.pdf }}" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> Download Help Guide PDF</a><br/><br/>
                <a ng-href="{{ guide.video }}" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> Download Video</a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I'm unable to bind any data into the video tag (which is a directive I've built) - so does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should help if you reference a different video in each repeat iteration ;-)

```
<div class="col-md-12">    
    <video src="{{guide.my_video_uri}}">
    </video>
</div>
```

If `src=".."` doesn't work, try `ng-src=".."`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have in fact, tried this - the video tag is a little misleading; as it a custom directive called "video". 

    <video video="{{ guide.video }}">
    </video>

this just brings up the error: Cannot GET /%7B%7B%20videoUrl%20%7D%7D

Comment: Did you write a directive that implements the video tag or an attribute "video"? I think the bug is inside this directive, so you should post this code here.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestion. I have in fact, tried this - the video tag is a little misleading; as it a custom directive called "video".

```
<video video="{{ guide.video }}">
</video>
```

this just brings up the error: Cannot GET /%7B%7B%20videoUrl%20%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

The directive brings in youtube embeds - which I am using for testing purposes first. The intention was to adjust the trustAsResourceUrl to another form of embed afterwards. The directive code is here below (i have changed the tag from video to video-player)

```
guideApp.directive('videoPlayer', function ($sce) {

'use strict';

return {

    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { video: '=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{ videoUrl }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('videoPlayer', function (videoLink) {
            if (videoLink) {
                scope.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoLink);
            }

        });

    }
};

});
```

Comment: The problem here is that the template is evaluated and the DOM is generated before the link function is called. Remove the template and generate it dynamically in the link function (the link functions gets the element itself as DOM object, change the declaration to `link: function(scope, element, attr) {..}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have fixed the issue by placing the url into a white list (the url is alos held within my JSON file and the template then pulls the link in via an iframe. Works exactly the way I need it to. Thank you for your help today. :)